# If $n \geq 3$ then there is no surjective homomorphism $f: D_{2n} \to Z_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

**Claim:** If $n \geq 3$ then there is no surjective homomorphism $f: D_{2n} \to Z_n$. In this case $D_{2n}$ refers to the dihedral group of order 2n.

**Thoughts:**

I'm thinking that the proof to this relies on orders between these groups since surjectivity is coming into play, but I don't know where to proceed from there. Any hints would be appreciated.

**Current attempt:**

Suppose there is a surjective homomorphism. Then since $n \geq 3$ we have $|D_{2n}| > |Z_n|$ so by pigeonhold principle $\exists x,y \in D_{2n}$ s.t. $f(x) = f(y) = z\in Z_n$

I think from here maybe find a contradiction by working with inverses?

Comment: Your thought about orders coming into play is correct, it implies that for every element of $Z_n$ there are exactly 2 elements of $D_{2n}$ mapping to it. Or looking at this from the perspective of $D_{2n}$: every element $x \in D_{2n}$ must have a twin brother $x'$ that is mapped to the same element of $Z_n$ Try to find a relation between $x$ and $x'$. For instance, what can/should $x^{-1}x'$ be?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951842/prove-there-is-no-surjective-homomorphism-between-d-4-the-symmetries-of-the-s) for $n=4$. The argument can be generalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the question in the comments (now deleted, but the question was: is it possible that for some $y \in Z_n$ there is only 1 $x \in D_{2n}$ mapping to it, for some other $y$ there are 2 such $x$ and for yet others 3 such $x$ etc.?), since it is at the same time a hint at how to approach the original question.

Let $f$ be the homomorphism. The claim is that for every $y \in Z_n$ there is an equal number of $x \in D_{2n}$ such that $f(x) = y$. (It then follows that this number must be 2 in this case, but for a surjection between any groups $G$ and $H$ the result also holds, just with a possibly different number).

Proof:

Let $e_1, \ldots, e_k$ be the elements that map to the identity element $e$ of $Z_n$. Let $y$ be a general element of $Z_n$ and let $x$ be any element such that $f(x) = y$. Then, since $f$ is a homomorphism we have that $f(xe_1) = y$, $f(xe_2) = y$, ..., $f(xe_k) =y$ so there are at least $k$ elements mapping to $y$.

Conversly suppose that $x'$ maps to $y$ as well then $x^{-1}x'$ maps to $e$ so $x^{-1}x' = e_i$ for one of the $i \in 1, \ldots, k$, so $x' = xe_i$. So when we were listing the elements $xe_1, ..., xe_k$ above we had indeed found all elements that map to $y$. Hence there are exactly $k$.

EDIT: Above is a proof of the fact that, for a surjection between groups $f: G \to H$ the number of elements in $G$ mapping to a given element $y$ in $H$ is the same for all $y$. I claimed at the beginning that the proof also contained a hint for the original question, but as stated that claim is a bit vague. What I meant by that is: in the above proof there is a special role for the set of elements in $D_{2n}$ that map to the identity in $Z_n$. My hint is: look closer at this set. What properties must it have? Then can you find any set with those properties inside $D_{2n}$?

Comment: For the first question: this cannot occur. If only 1 element maps to the identity of $Z_n$ then the above proof states that for any $y \in Z_n$ exactly 1 element of $D_{2n}$ maps there. So there are $n$ elements in $D_{2n}$ that map somewhere (one for each element of $Z_n$) and $n$ elements that map nowhere because all spots are taken. But that is absurd. Every element maps somewhere because $f$ is a map.

Comment: For the second question: we need not assume that $y$ is mapped from at leat 2 points, the proof still works if $x' = x$. We *do* need to assume that $y$ mapped to from *at least one* point, but this is given by the assumption that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: It can happen with random maps, but not with group homomorphisms!

Comment: Let's say $u$ and $v$ are different and both mapped to $y$. Where does $u^{-1}$ go? Obviously it goes to $y^{-1}$. Ok but then where does $u^{-1}v$ go? Well to $f(u^{-1})f(v) = y^{-1}y = e$, where $e$ is the identity element in the recieving group. So far so good. But now, suppose that, as in your example there is only one element, namely the identity element of the sending group that is mapped to $e$. Then we find that $u^{-1}v$, being an element that is mapped tot $e$ must be the identity. But that implies that $u = v$ from the beginning which we assumed was not the case...

Comment: Do you understand the kernel of a group homomorphism, and the cosets of the kernel, and the theorem that any coset of the kernel has the same cardinality as the kernel?

Comment: Would it not also work to say, once we have that each $y \in Z_{n}$ has to come from an equal number of $x \in D_{2n}$, combined with the consequence of a homomorphism that $f(e_{D_{2n}}) = e_{Z_{n}}$ and the fact that each reflection in $D_{2n}$ is its own inverse, that it follows that all $n$ reflections in $D_{2n}$ must get mapped to the only element in $Z_n$ that is its own inverse (which only exists if $n$ is even), contradicting that each $y \in Z_{n}$ has to come from an equal number of $x \in D_{2n}$?

Comment: Clarification: my comments above are in answer to now deleted comments by the OP

Answer (score 2):

$\;\;\;$In the dihedral group $D_n$ of size $2n,n\geq3,$ on the regular $n$-gon a rotation $R_{\theta}$ of degree $\theta, 0<\theta<360,$ never commutes with a reflection $S_j$ over the symmetry axis through vertex $j=1,2,\dots,n$. Therefore, the group center $\mathcal Z(D_n)$ is trivial ; i.e. $\mathcal Z(D_n)=\{\iota\}$.

$\;\;\;$If such a surjective group homomorphism $\psi:D_n\to\Bbb Z_n$ exists then by the fundamental theorem of group homomorphisms we'd have $\frac{D_n}{\ker(\psi)}\approx\Bbb Z_n$ and thus $$\frac{|D_n|}{|\ker(\psi)|}=|\Bbb Z_n|\;;\;\frac{2n}{|\ker(\psi)|}=n$$ implying $\ker(\psi)=\{\iota,\alpha\}$ has size $2$. Because $\ker(\psi)$ is normal we'd have $x\alpha x^{-1}=\alpha$ for all $x\in D_n$ implying $\alpha\in\mathcal Z(D_n)$ which is impossible because the group center $\mathcal Z(D_n)$ must be trivial. Therefore, no such surjective group homomorphism exists.